# getting Exception while Getting Location using CrossGeolocator in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am working on xamarin . I want to track user . i saw some code over internet.
I applied that code into my project But i am getting Exception.

> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
>   assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main
>   application project in order to reference the platform-specific
>   implementation.

My Code is

```
 var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
 locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

 var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000));
 lbl1.Text = position.Latitude.ToString();
 lbl2.Text = position.Longitude.ToString();
```

Comment: You also need to add the package in your application projects, review the error your posted: **You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation**

Comment: i am new in Xamarin can you please tell me step by step how to do this

Comment: Add the same nuget package that you added to your PCL project to your the iOS and Android projects in your solution...